# Identifying values for arguments in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharpffmpeg

I'm searching online for converting video and capturing thumbnail image after uploading the video file. I found something similar with this link http://ramcrishna.blogspot.com/2008/09/playing-videos-like-youtube-and.html but there's something I want to clarify on it. On the argument section he declared string value which shown like this

```
 string filargs = "-i\"" + inputfile + "\" -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320×240 -aspect 4:3 -y \"" + outputfile + "\"";
```

I want to know what is the exact actual value for 'inputfile' and 'outputfile' variable that he declared on the argument string? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Get Environment.CommandLine and parse it into strings such as:

```
string[] commandLineParts = Environment.CommandLine.Split(' ');
```

Now you can iterate through the strings in the array and parse out what you to process, based on the argument starting with "-i\" or "-y\"

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about that line of code you've given. I thought inputfile and outputfile are variables that you just add it on the argument string.

Comment: just like if inputfile=fileupload1.postedfile.filename; but I'm not sure about that.